# Atribuir valores de ListBox em vetor

Tags: c#, winforms

Ao jogar os itens um a um dentro de um vetor, posição 0 com 0 e assim por diante, funciona corretamente. 
Porém o código apresenta um mau funcionamento pois ,na primeira iteração vai normal logo na segunda da erro:

> InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'.
>   Esta certo que a posição 1, não é index, mais não estou querendo selecionar o index da list.

```
for (j = 0; j <= notas_operacao; j++)   <== quantidade de notas no listbox
            {
                foreach (var item in listBox_Nfe.Items) <==== corre listBox
                {
                    notas[j] = listBox_Nfe.Items[j].ToString(); <==deveria jogar list item atual em posição de vetor em j
                    MessageBox.Show(notas[j]); => debug
                }
            }
```

Comment: Só com estre trecho fica difícil avaliar.

Comment: Simplesmente é essa paste de minha aplicação que esta falhando, essa hora em que tento pegar todos os itens de uma listbox e jogar em um vetor string

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Se vc faz um `foreach` de cada elemento da `listBox`, pq não alocar no `notas` a variável `item` do `foreach`? Na verdade vc nem precisa do for externo, só o `foreach` basta, é só colocar uma variável `j` fora e `j++` dentro do `foreach`

Comment: Exato era exatamente isso.

Answer (score 2):

Será isto o que você pretende:

```
foreach (var item in listBox_Nfe.Items) <==== corre listBox
{
    int j = 0;
    notas[j] = item.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(notas[j]);
    j++;
}
```

A informação que você dá não é muita, por isso posso estar errado.

Comment: É isso, só com um pequeno ajuste notas[j] = listBox_Nfe.Items[j].ToString(); muito obrigado

Comment: A variável do foreach `item` deveria ser igual a `listBox_Nfe.Items[j]`